# Retorno getJSON

Tags: php

Quando o getJSON, não encontra ele o que é retornado? Estou deixando como fazio, mas não da certo.

```
$("#email").focusout(function() {
            emailDigitado = $("#email").val();
            $.getJSON("inc_verificaCadastro.php", {email:emailDigitado}, function(json){

                if (json[0].email == ''){
                    $('#divSenha').attr('class', 'mostrar');
                    $("#senha").attr("required", true);
                }else{
                    $("#id_cadastro").val(json[0].id_cadastro);
                }
            });
        });
```

arquivo inc_verificaCadastro.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
include 'config.php';

$rs = $conexao->query("SELECT ID_Cadastro, email FROM cadastro WHERE email = '".$_GET['email']."' ");

$Array = Array();
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
    $Array[] = Array(
        "email"         => $row['email'],
        "id_cadastro"   => $row['ID_Cadastro']
    );
}
$json_encode = json_encode($Array);
echo $json_encode;
?>
```

Comment: @bfavaretto Editei o post inicial. Mesmo assim não esta entrando no IF inicial.

Comment: @bfavaretto Ahhhh... veja se estou certo. Quando a busca não é feita com sucesso `json[0].email` retorna fazio. Então não tem como comparar nada com vazio.

Comment: Testa se `json.length > 0` antes de mexer na resposta do servidor

Comment: @bfavaretto Deu certo, coloquei `json.length != 1`

Comment: ??? `!= 1` ele vai entrar no if se tiver 0 ou 2+, e no else se tiver exatamente 1.

Comment: @bfavaretto Aqui deu certo assim...rsrs.

Answer (score 0):

Para verificares se o json esta em branco, tenta o seguinta

```
if (!$.trim(json)){   
    alert("a variavel json esta em branco " + json);
}
else{   
    alert("a variavel json não esta em branco: " + json);
}
```